# Collections.sort with comparator inside runnable return duplicated items?

Tags: java, android, collections, runnable

i am trying to sort a list of contacts(android/car/telephony/common/Contact.java) that does not contain duplicated items:

```
    private void updateSortedContactList() {
    if (mContactListLiveData.getValue() == null && getValue() == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (mContactListLiveData.getValue() == null
            || mContactListLiveData.getValue().isEmpty()) {
        setValue(null);
        return;
    }
        List<Contact> contactList = mContactListLiveData.getValue();

    if (mRunnableFuture != null) {
        mRunnableFuture.cancel(true);
    }
    Runnable runnable = () -> {
        Collections.sort(contactList, comparator);
        postValue(new Pair<>(sortMethod, contactList));
    };
    mRunnableFuture = mExecutorService.submit(runnable);
}
```

as a result of this method, some times( not frequently) i get the same size list but with items that were removed, and items that were duplicated,

ps: it's not always the same items that where duplicated/removed

Comment: If you're modifying the `contactList` outside of the `Runnable` as well, you need to properly synchronize access to it.

Comment: i added more details about my function, i don't think that contactList has been edited @RobSpoor

Comment: Well, `contactList` comes from `mContactListLiveData.getValue()`. If that doesn't return a copy but its internal list itself, then updating that list through `mContactListLiveData` will still update `contactList`. If that occurs while it's being sorted in a different thread, the results will be unpredictable.